# java and json jackson property - different types at run-time

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am calling an external web-service to get an object as json. This object has a property "value" which is sometimes a String and sometimes an array of Strings.

```
public class MyClass {

    // ... other variables

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @JsonProperty("value")
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Currently, I get an error `org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token` complaining about this field. I was wondering if some one could give me a hint on what is the correct way of defining `value` in my class.

This is a part of a sample json that I have to deal with:

```
    {
      "id": 12016907001,
      "type": "Create",
      "value": "normal",
      "field_name": "priority"
    },
    {
      "id": 12016907011,
      "type": "Create",
      "value": [
        "sample",
        "another"
      ],
      "field_name": "tags"
    }
```

Thanks.

**-- EDIT**

I changed the type of the value to Object and it solved my problem. However, I am still wondering if there is a better way to handle this case.

Comment: Do you have any control over the external web-service?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple hack would be to enable [DeserializationFeature#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) and then use Daniel's answer. If the web service returns a string, Jackson will turn it into a single-element collection.

EDIT:

If you can't upgrade to Jackson 1.8 or higher to use this feature, you could do something like:

```
private Collection<String> value;

public Collection<String> getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Object value) {
    if (value instanceof Collection) {
        this.value = (Collection<String>) value;
    } else {
        this.value = Arrays.asList((String) value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems very interesting but i am using `org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig` not `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature` and it doesn't have this configuration!

Comment: Well, changing the type of 'value' to Object solved my problem. However, I think your solution looks like the best solution and therefore I accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: This option appears to be in Jackson 1.8.0+ so if you can get to that version or higher you can use it.

Comment: Thank you so much HiJon89, I changed the version to the current one (1.9.12), and now I can have `List<String> value` without any problem, thanks for the help!

Comment: for Jackson 2.2 need to us objectMapper.configure(
                DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY,
                true);

Answer (score 0):

value is an array so it can't be converted to a string.

You're java class should be something like the following:

```
class MyClass
{
   public int id;
   public String type;
   public Collection<String> value;
   public String field_name;
}
```

I'm using public fields for example (this will work fine).

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. The external service doesn't have a consistent definition for the `value` field. Sometimes it is an array and sometimes it's just a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonNode](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) as type for your value. Afterwards you can process your value dependent on the return values of `isArray()` (or `isValueNode()`). I think that JsonNodes are the most convenient way way to handle raw JSON because they offer a broad functionality beyond those simple checks.

```
if (value.isArray()) {

    // process your array

} else {

    // process your string

}
```