# Java - Using @JsonProperty to parse properties with the same name but different types

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using `@JsonProperty` in a generic model Parser to extract classes from a feed.
The problem I'm having is that a specific property may have different types.

E.g: `@JsonProperty("house")` In some json files the `house` is a `List<Rooms>` and in the other is a `Map<Rooms>`, but the property name is always the same.

What can I do?

Thank you for your Help

Comment: possible duplicate of [java and json jackson property - different types at run-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626384/java-and-json-jackson-property-different-types-at-run-time)

Comment: What version of Jackson are you using?